# How to include the same library in different linux distros with node-gyp

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, node-gyp, node-addon-api

I'm trying to build my project on linux but I need to use two shared libraries (SDL2 and SDL2 image), the problem is that the path to the libraries depends on the distro. For example:
on Ubuntu the libraries are saved in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` but on Fedora are saved in `/usr/lib64/`. How can I make a single binding.gyp file for all distros?
This is the current binding.gyp file:

```py
{
    'targets': [
        {
            'target_name': 'canvas_sdl2',
            'sources': [
                'src/init.cpp',
                'src/sdl2node.cpp',
                'src/sdl2image_node.cpp',
                'src/common.cpp'
            ],
            'cflags!': ['-fno-exceptions'],
            'cflags_cc!': ['-fno-exceptions'],
            'xcode_settings': {
                'GCC_ENABLE_CPP_EXCEPTIONS': 'YES',
                'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY': 'libc++',
                'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET': '10.7'
            },
            'msvs_settings': {
                'VCCLCompilerTool': {'ExceptionHandling': 1},
            },
            'dependencies': [
                "<!(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').gyp\")"
            ],
            'include_dirs': [
                        "<(module_root_dir)/include/sdl/",
                        "<(module_root_dir)/include/sdlimg/",
                        "<!@(node -p \"require('node-addon-api').include\")",
                    ],
            'conditions': [
                ["OS==\"win\"", {
                    'libraries': [
                        "<(module_root_dir)/bin/sdl/winx64/SDL2.lib",
                        "<(module_root_dir)/bin/sdlimg/winx64/SDL2_image.lib",
                    ],
                    'copies': [
                        {
                            'destination': '<(module_root_dir)/build/Release/',
                            'files': [
                                '<(module_root_dir)/bin/sdl/winx64/SDL2.dll',
                                '<(module_root_dir)/bin/sdlimg/winx64/SDL2_image.dll'
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }],
                ["OS==\"linux\"", {
                    "libraries": [
                        "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0",
                        "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0",
                    ]
                    # How can I make it compatible with other distributions?
                }]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I honestly haven't found much online and haven't tried much.

**EDIT:**
What i tried:
I changed the absoulte path into `-lSDL2` and with ubuntu it still works but with fedora I get this error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL2: File or directory does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting

```py
"libraries": [
    "-L$(LIB)", "-lSDL2"
]
```

Where "-L$(LIB)" is the path to the folder that contains all the libraries